# Alternative words of phrases for "confirmation feedback"?

Tags: synonyms

What I mean by *confirmation feedback* is imagine you're filling out an online form of some sort, and once you reach the end of it you press the submit button. If the page doesn't prompt a text message saying something like *'Your form was successfully submitted'* or doesn't redirect you somewhere else, and instead, remains on the same page and processes your form submission in the background, you might think the page did not record your form submission. If the page, however, gives you some confirmation feedback, like redirects you to a different page, you can rest assured knowing you submission was valid.

What are some alternative ways of saying what I'm trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A '**Submission Response**' would convey that a response had been made after a successful submission.

Comment: I always turn to complicated alternatives, this is simple and conveys exactly that. Thanks!